# How to get an 8 decimal output?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get an 8 decimal output from the following function.

The following function multiplies an input by 2 and then updates this input with the wagerUpdate variable. I would like this outputted number to have 8 decimal places.

For example: if input number is 0.00000001 (this code is for a bitcoin website), then I would like output number to be 0.00000002. For some reason the code below is not working properly as the output number is in the format of 2e-8 without the .toFixed(8) code. Please help if you are able to. Thank you so much.

```
<script>
function MultiplyWagerFunction() {
var wager = document.getElementById("wagerInputBox").value;
var wagerUpdate = wager*2;
document.getElementById("wagerInputBox").value = +wagerUpdate.toFixed(8);  
}
</script>
```

Comment: Why are you doing `+wagerUpdate`? It's already a number by virtue of the fact you multiplied it by a number. Remove that and your `toFixed` should work.

Comment: @MattBurland Post that as an answer.

Comment: I have updated earlier question you had asked. Removed +.

Comment: Also, using javascript floating point arithmetic for financial calculations is [never a good idea](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458633/how-to-deal-with-floating-point-number-precision-in-javascript) (as you mentioned bitcoin).

Answer (score 1):

If you remove the `+` before `wagerUpdate.toFixed(8)` it should work fine. `wagerUpdate` has already be converted to a number when you multiplied it by `2` so there should be no need for the unary `+`

```js
var a = "0.00000001";
var b = a*2;
console.log(b.toFixed(8));
console.log(+b.toFixed(8));
```

^ see the difference.

The reason it doesn't work is because what you are doing is equivalent to:

```
+(b.toFixed(8))
```

because of the [precedence of the operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) (member access `.` is higher than unary `+`). You are converting `b` to a string with `.toFixed` and then converting it back into a number with `+` and then *converting it back into a string again!* (this time with the default `toString` behavior for numbers giving you exponential notation)

Comment: `toFixed(8)` converts it from a number to a string. The problem is that he really wants the string, he doesn't want to convert it back to a number, because when it gets converted back to a string to assign to `.value` it will use exponential notation instead of fixed notation.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove + from `+wagerUpdate.toFixed(8);` and you would be good.

Comment: Awesome. I changed it and everything is working well now. I am new to coding so this has really helped me. Thank you!

Answer (score -3):

Instead of:

```
document.getElementById("wagerInputBox").value = +wagerUpdate.toFixed(8);
```

try:

```
document.getElementById("wagerInputBox").innerHTML = +wagerUpdate.toFixed(8);
```

Why I say so is may be when you set value, browser tries to convert to best possible outcome. But, inner HTML should take the string equivalent!

Comment: If `wagerInputBox` is an `<input>` it doesn't have `innerHTML`, only `value`.

Comment: Oh yes! I did not consider that. My Bad.

May be the '+' sign cause problem as Matt has pointed